# One User model for Auth and User Django

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-users

I'm using the Django auth feature to create users. I also want to extend the user to add things like profile pictures and other information.

My problem is that I now have to User models to manage. One from Auth and one from the model I created. Can this be consolidated into one model?

from urls.py:

```
path('accounts/',include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))
```

from models.py:

```
class User(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image= models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image',default='profile_image/SSMILE.jpg')
```

from views.py

```
class SignUp(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'signup.html'
```

[image: I have 2 User models]

As you can see I have 2 User models. I have to end up creating the auth user through sign up then in my homepage view do this:

```
if str(request.user) != "AnonymousUser":
    try:
        getuser = User.objects.get(user=request.user)
        print(getuser)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        newUser= User(user=request.user,firstName=request.user,lastName="change")
        newUser.save()
```

which is a hack I want to avoid doing.

Comment: There is a nice documentation for customizing user model: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model

Comment: best way is customizing model   
https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding another model with same name User. It is already there. If you are extending your user model, then you don't need to add first_name or last_name any more,

Check this,

```
class Profile(models.Model):
   profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to=#add your path)
   user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
      Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
     instance.profile.save()
```

This will extend your existing user model.

Comment: Thanks Bidhan, When I try to remove my User Model to replace it with the Profile model I get this error when I try to migrate django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "fc_user" does not exist Would you know how to solve this please?

Comment: Managed to sort it out, had to delete migrations relating to user and then create profile. Thank you